# Is `indefinitely` an equivalence of `endless`?

Tags: word-meaning

The [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indefinitely) uses `endless` and `forever` to explain `indefinitely`.

The oxford dictionary defines `indefinitely` as *"for an unlimited or unspecified period of time"*, I think `unlimited` just means not sure, which might be a short time, or a long time.

Any comments?

Comment: I think you're wrong in your understanding of *unlimited*. It's a simple word, with a simple meaning that can easily be established using any dictionary. Essentially, an *unlimited* period has no limit, so it definitely goes on forever, whereas an *unspecified* period probably does have an end point (we just don't know *when* the end will come).

Answer (score 2):

*Endless* and *indefinite* are slightly different.

- An *endless* state will (of course) never end, under any circumstances. It goes on forever.
- An *indefinite* state is a state that has no known end point, but could end eventually (or may not). Its end time is *not known* or *not defined* (thus, *in-definite*).

> Once the sun goes out, there will be *endless* darkness in the sky.

The will *never* be light in the sky again, without the sun. This darkness will go on forever.

> I don't know when I will get money to fix my car, so I need to use your car indefinitely.

There is no fixed end point to borrowing your car. I need your car until I get more money, which may or may not happen at some unknown point in the future. I *might* need to borrow your car forever, or I might need it for a limited time. I don't know, and cannot *define* the length of time I will need it.

In short, *indefinitely* allows the possibility of an end (at an unknown time), but it does not promise an end.